Loading huggingface dataset from in-memory text
I have in-memory text, json format, and I am trying to load dataset (HuggingFace) directly from text in-memory.
If I will save it into file - I can load the dataset using huggingface load_dataset:
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset('json', data_files='my_file.json')

See also: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.11.0/loading_datasets.html#from-local-files
Can I load the dataset directly from the in-memory text without saving it into file?

Build a dict from the json, then build the dataset object yourself:

import json
import datasets

the_json_string = "..." # you define this obviously

the_dict = json.loads(the_json_string) # loads builds a dict from a string

dataset_object = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(the_dict)


Look at the documentation for datasets.Dataset.from_dict for exactly how to make this work:
https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.2.1/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.from_dict

thanx! ....and how can I do the same for other file types, like jsonl or csv?

yes, you just parse the file first and then convert it with one of the many constructor functions. look at the ref link, there are other ones
